# How to open/write/commit database from User's Google drive instead of using local storage

Tags: android, database, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create an app where the user can access his data (from a database) using multiple devices.  I'm plan to do this by saving/editing/storing the database in the user's google drive account and use Google's Drive API's.  I've spent time doing research on the subject Google's examples aren't of much help.  So far i'm able to use the Drive API to access the user's Google Drive but i don't know how Open, edit and post the database.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to use a db-helper class to open the database directly from the user's account?
2. Can i accomplish this using Google Drive APIs? i don't want to have access to the contents of the user's database so if it could be saved in their drive would be great.

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Drive only understands "upload" and "download", so you would need to decide on a storage format (eg. JSON or CSV), and then download-parse-read-modify-pack-upload each time.

A couple of alternative approaches to consider:-

1. use the Spreadsheet API https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/
2. use file properties https://developers.google.com/drive/web/properties
3. use the appdata (appfolder) api  https://developers.google.com/drive/web/appdata

It might be worth explaining a bit more about the size, shape and usage of your database to elicit better alternatives

Comment: thanks, I plan to use several linked SQL databases... i.e. customerList_db, customer_transactions_db, Customer_payments, ect. The user will hold it's customers' data and have the ability to sync them to the cloud so he could access to it from his phone, tablet, or any other devices and always have the data up to data.

Comment: I've taken a look at Parse.com and other services like that one but they don't seem to address the scenario i have.  Maybe i'm not looking the right way.  What should be able to address data sync like this?

Comment: Important to note is that it's not my customer data but the user's.
I won't hold the customer data, each user will have their own customers data they want to manage.... so i don't need direct access to their databases

Comment: tricky. I guess on the one hand, you don't want users' files on your quota; on the other hand, you don't want the user to have to provision his own cloud storage, which is why you're looking at the auto-provisioned drive. Of the pure Google options, Spreadsheet API comes closest to a cloud database. I found this link, but can't vouch for it https://code.google.com/p/google-spreadsheet-lib-android/

Comment: this might be another approach http://www.aspose.com/android/excel-component.aspx. Treat a local excel spreadsheet as your database and let standard Drive sync take care of the cloud aspect,

Comment: Watch out for the Google cloud event on 4th November. Given the Firebase absorption, I have a hunch that your use case is on their sites.